# How to change Day/Month/Year format to Month/Day/Year in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column that the date is in Day/Month/Year format and it is stored in object format. How can I change it to Month/Day/Year format in python?

Here is an example: How can I change 13/3/2021 to 3/13/2021?

Comment: is it a dataframe column in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is using split:

```py
def convert_format1(s: str):
    d, m, y = s.split("/")
    return "/".join((m, d, y))
```

Or you can use `datetime` module to convert string to datetime object(`.strptime`) and vice versa(`.strftime`):

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convert_format2(s: str):
    source_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
    destination_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    d = datetime.strptime(s, source_format)
    return d.strftime(destination_format)
```

You can then apply these functions to your dataframe's column.

**note**: AFAIK `.strftime()` method adds zero padding to the string representation of day and month. If you don't want this behavior you have to strip it manually after that.

**note**: second function is safer since it checks the dates to be valid as well.

Comment: The second solution works! Thanks!

Comment: @XinyiChen Happy to help. Could you accept this as the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
t = datetime.date.today()
print(t.month,t.day,t.year,sep="/")
```

change the value inside the print should let you set yourself